# Recommended way to populate a WTForm from API call

Tags: python, flask, flask-wtforms, eve

I am using flask with WTforms to edit data from a python-eve based API 
I get this object from the API (keep you eye on the '_id' and '_etag':

```
{
    "_updated": "Sun, 06 Apr 2014 12:49:11 GMT",
    "name": "moody",
    "question": "how are you?",
    "_links": {
        "self": {
            "href": "127.0.0.1:5000/surveys/533e9f88936aa21dd410d4f1",
            "title": "Survey"
        },
        "parent": {
            "href": "127.0.0.1:5000",
            "title": "home"
        },
        "collection": {
            "href": "127.0.0.1:5000/surveys",
            "title": "surveys"
        }
    },
    "_created": "Fri, 04 Apr 2014 12:03:20 GMT",
    "_id": "533e9f88936aa21dd410d4f1",
    "_etag": "7d11e7f57ed306043d76c05257474670eccde91c"
}
```

I want to edit the object in a WTForm, so I create define the form:

```
class surveyForm(Form):
    _id = HiddenField("_id")
    _etag = HiddenField("_etag")
    name = TextField("Name")
    question = TextField("question")
    submit = SubmitField("Send")
```

initiate the form:

```
obj = getSurvey(id) # here I get the object from the API            
form = surveyForm(**obj)
return render_template('surveyAdd.html', form=form)
```

and render the form:

```
<form class="form-horizontal" role="form" action="{{ url_for('surveyAddOrEdit') }}" method=post>

    {{ form.hidden_tag() }}

    {{ form._id }}
    {{ form._etag }}

    {{ form.name.label }}
    {{ form.name(class="form-control") }}

    {{ form.question.label }}
    {{ form.question(class="form-control") }}

    {{ form.submit(class="btn btn-default") }}
</form>
```

and the result is:

```
<form class="form-horizontal" role="form" action="/survey/add" method="post">

<div style="display:none;"><input id="csrf_token" name="csrf_token" type="hidden" value="1396959127.36##dc263965e20ecc9956fc25d5b5c96f90f311cf47"></div>

&lt;UnboundField(HiddenField, ('_id',), {})&gt;
&lt;UnboundField(HiddenField, ('_etag',), {})&gt;
<label for="name">Name</label>
<input class="form-control" id="name" name="name" type="text" value="moody">
<label for="question">question</label>
<input class="form-control" id="question" name="question" type="text" value="how are you?">
<input class="btn btn-default" id="submit" name="submit" type="submit" value="Send">
```

Bummer...the hidden '_id' field and '_etag' fields don't get rendered. I just get an UnboundField 
Notice that the underscores get striped, which is the problem.

I think it would be optimal if I could load objects directly from the API and into a form, and after editing feed it directly back to the API...but I can't due to the stripped uderscores. Instead I alter the object - rename '_id' to 'id' and '_etag' to ''etag' - and that works.

So I have 2 questions:

1. is there a way objects directly into the form without altering them
2. what is the recommended way of interaction with an API. Is it better to have client side methods that load and sanitise objects

Cheers!